# VBA: extract a date stamp from HTML table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to extract the date in `<td>6/19/2017 9:49:14 AM</td>`. `<td>Time extracted</td>` allways in in the same row `OddRow`. Would `.getElementsByTagName("td")(*).innerText` work correctly everytime?

[image]

Comment: without knowing it's parent object, I couldn't say.  I doubt it as it's the 2nd OddRow.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav You think it would be good to build an array of all `<td>` tags and `instr` the date to search for?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I presume.

```
Sub Scrape_HTML()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "your_URL_here"

' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

                        Set Links = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")
                        RowCount = 1

                            ' Scrape out the innertext of each 'td' element.
                            With Sheets("DataSheet")
                                For Each lnk In Links
                                    .Range("A" & RowCount) = lnk.innerText
                                    RowCount = RowCount + 1
                                Next
                            End With

End Sub
```